# C++ Vector Initialize with INT_MIN crash

Tags: c++

I need some of your wisdom:

Why this cannot be done:

```
std::vector<int> min(INT_MIN, 3);
```

"C++ exception: std::length_error at memory location 0x0000009AA63CF0A0."

And this way apparently worked:

```
    std::vector<int> min;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        large.push_back(INT_MIN);
```

Comment: The first argument is the size, the second argument is the value.  So you're using `INT_MIN` for the size, and `3` for the value to store.

Comment: Be careful with the variable name, using `min` may cause you headaches, especially on windows. Of course you may not be using that name in your actual code, but just in case...

Answer (score 2):

`INT_MIN` is a large negative value. It gets converted to `size_t` which is unsigned, and becomes a large positive value - apparently, larger than `max_size()`.

You might have meant to create a vector with three elements, each equal to `INT_MIN`. In this case, you are specifying arguments the wrong way round. Make it

```
std::vector<int> min(3, INT_MIN);
```

Comment: That's Exactly what I wanted to do, my bad, Thanks.